# Distance from $A(1, 2, 2)$ to the line $\frac{x-1}{-5}=\frac{y+1}{3}=\frac{z+1}{3}$

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, analytic-geometry, 3d

I need to find the distance from the point $A(1, 2, 2)$ to the line $l:\frac{x-1}{-5}=\frac{y+1}{3}=\frac{z+1}{3}$.
I thought that I should find the perpendicular from $A$ to my line, intersect these two lines and then I have my distance.
Let's say that the perpendicular from $A$ to $l$ has the direction $(a, b, c)$. Then we must have that $-5a+3b+3c=0$.
Now, what I did was I chose the particular solution $(0, -1, 1)$ and I obtained the line $\frac{x-1}{0}=\frac{y-2}{-1}=\frac{z-2}{1}$, I intersected $l$ and this line and I got the distance to be $3\sqrt{2}$.
I would like to know if this is correct. I wonder if it is alright to pick a particular solution of  $-5a+3b+3c=0$. I have a feeling that if this were right, I would be getting that there are multiple perpendiculars from $A$ to $l$ and this is wrong. Are all these lines the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot pick a particular solution to $a, b, c$. Please note that the equation of the line is,

$\displaystyle \small l: \frac{x-1}{-5}=\frac{y+1}{3}=\frac{z+1}{3}$, so a point $P$ on the line will be given by $x = 1-5t, y = z = 3t-1$

Hence the direction vector from point $A (1, 2, 2)$ to point $P$ on the line is $\vec {AP} = (-5t, 3t-3, 3t-3)$.

When $\vec {AP} $ is perpendicular to line $l$, the dot product of $\vec {AP}$ with the direction vector of line $l$ will be zero.

$-5 \cdot (-5t) + 3 \cdot (3t-3) + 3 \cdot (3t-3) = 0 \implies t = \frac{18}{43}$

Now plug in value of $t$ to find $|\vec{AP}|$ which is the distance you seek.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, your solution really makes sense. Could you tell me why I cannot pick a particular solution to $a, b, c$? This is the part that I really don't understand, because, in my case, the dot product is $0$ and my line passes through $A$. Why isn't it perpendicular, though?

Comment: Pick a point $X$ on line $l$. Now say we have a plane passing through $X$ whose normal vector is same as the direction vector of the line $l$ (in other words, the plane is perp to $l$) then any line drawn from $X$ in the plane is perpendicular to the line. But not all of them go through point $(1, 2, 2)$. That is why we cannot pick any arbitrary solution to $-5a+3b+3c=0$

Comment: Okay, I get what you say, but I thought that I solved this issue because I made my line pass through the point $(1, 2, 2)$. So, my line is perpendicular on $l$ (because the dot product of the direction vectors is $0$) and it passes through $A$. Or at least I think it does. What exactly am I missing in this reasoning? Sorry if this is all really trivial, but I really want to understand this.

Comment: @TheZone on your last point, I am glad you are trying to understand this. That is what study is all about. Now coming back to your confusion, yes you set the direction and you made the line pass through point $(1, 2, 2)$ but think of my previous comment. How do you know that these lines will intersect? Even if they did, you are lucky that they did because choosing arbitrary direction, there is little chance that you will get the right direction.

Comment: And even in this case those lines do not intersect.

Comment: Point on $l$ is given by $x = 1-5t, y = z = 3t-1$, point on the new line you came up with is given by $x = 1, y = 2 - s, z = 2 + s$. Equating $x$, you get $t = 0$ then equating $y$ gives you $s = 3$. Now plug in $t$ and $s$ in both $z$. Do you get the same value of $z$?

Comment: Ah, I see, so basically what I am missing is that by choosing a random direction I am not really sure that my lines intersect. Okay, this makes sense. One more question: I knew that as soon as I had two lines whose direction vectors were perpendicular (i.e. their dot product=0) I could say that the lines are perpendicular. Is this incomplete? Because here we have two lines whose direction vectors are perpendicular, yet are not perpendicular.

Comment: Yes just because direction vectors of the lines are perpendicular does not mean that lines intersect. Think of a simple example. You have x-axis and you have y-axis. They are perp and they intersect. Now you draw a line just above y-axis parallel to y-axis (i.e. same direction) but not at $z = 0$, instead at say $z = 2$. The direction vectors of x-axis and this new line are perpendicular but the lines would never intersect.

Comment: Thank you, now it makes sense! My lines are perpendicular, but for the specific  problem I wish to solve I need a perpendicular that actually intersect my line $l$.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Is my last comment correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124208/discussion-between-math-lover-and-thezone).

Answer (score 0):

Line: $\frac{x-x_1}l=\frac{y-y_1}m=\frac{z-z_1}n$

Point:$A(x_0, y_0, z_0)$

$d=\frac{\sqrt{{\begin{vmatrix}y_0-y_1&z_0-z_1\\m&n\end{vmatrix}}^2+{\begin{vmatrix}z_0-z_1&x_0-x_1\\n&l\end{vmatrix}}^2+{\begin{vmatrix}x_0-x_1&y_0-y_1\\l&m\end{vmatrix}}^2}}{\sqrt{l^2+m^2+n^2}}$

Line:: $\frac{x-1}{-5}=\frac{y+1}3=\frac{z+1}3\rightarrow l=-5, m=3, n=3$

Point: $A(x_0=1,y_0= 2, z_0= 2)$

Plugging values in formula we get:

$d=\frac{15\sqrt{86}}{43}\approx 3.23$

Answer (score 0):

The line $\frac{x−1}{−5}=\frac{y+1}{3}= \frac{z+1}{3}$ has tangent vector <-1/5, 1/3, 1/3> which is, of course, a normal vector to any plane perpendicar to that line.  In particular, the plane containing the point (1, 2, 2) perpendicular to that line is (-1/5)(x- 1)+ (1/3)(y- 2)+ (1/3(z- 2)= 0 or -3(x- 1)+ 5(y- 2)+ 5(z- 3)= -3x+ 5y+ 5z- 22= 0 so -3x+ 5y+ 5z= 22.

The line $\frac{x−1}{−5}=\frac{y+1}{3}= \frac{z+1}{3}$ has parametic equation x= -5t+ 1, y= 3t- 1, z= 3t- 1.  That line will intersect the plane where $-3(-5t+ 1)+ 5(3t- 1)+ 5(3t- 1)= 45t- 7= 22.  45t= 29 so t= 29/45.  That is, the point of intersectoin is x= -5(29/45)+ 1= -29/9+ 1= -20/9, y= 3(29/45)- 1= 29/15- 1= 14/15, and z= 3(29/45)- 1= 29/15- 1= 14/15.

All that is left is to compute the distance between (1, 2, 2) and (-20/9, 14/15, 14/15)

Answer (score 0):

After converting to parametric form, $(x,y,z) = (1-5t, 3t-1, 3t-1)$.

Thus for any $t$, the *squared* distance to the point $(1,2,2)$ is: $$(1-5t-1)^2 + 2(3t-1-2)^2 = 25t^2 + 2(9t^2 - 18t + 9) = 43t^2 - 36t +18.$$

Since $a > 0$, this quadratic is concave up, and hence the minimum distance is attained at $t = -\frac{b}{2a} = -\frac{-36}{2 (43)} = \frac{18}{43}$. Substituting this value of $t$ in gives $d = \sqrt{\frac{450}{43}} \approx 3.23$.

Answer (score 0):

The parametric equation for the line gives Po (1,-1,-1) and its direction vector as -5i+3j+3k.
First method:
Take the dot product of Po>A with the direction vector and use this to find the angle in between.  The perpendicular distance from A to the line is then the modulus of Po>A times the sine of that angle.
...  Po>A = 0i+3j+3k and so the dot product of Po>A is 18.  The modulus of Po>A is Sqrt(18) and the modulus of the direction vector is Sqrt(43), and so the angle is the inverse cosine of 18/(sqrt(18)*sqrt(43)) = 49.68 deg.  The distance is sqrt(18)*sin(49.68) = 3.23.
Second method:
Since we see that the distance involves the sine of the angle, we could use the cross product between Po>A and the direction vector, taking the modulus of this product and dividing by the modulus of the direction vector only.  The cross product is 0i+15j+15k, and the modulus of this is sqrt(450).  The distance is given by sqrt(450)/sqrt(43) = 3.23.
Done.